# Access SQL NOT LIKE Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to return a list of salesperson_ids and salesperson_lnames where the salesperson_id does not have customers in FL or HI.

My current query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.salesperson_id, s.salesperson_lname
FROM salesperson_t AS s inner join customer_t AS c on s.salesperson_id=c.salesperson_id
WHERE c.state not in ('HI', 'FL');
```

And it returns a list excluding only salesperson_id and salesperson_lname if they have customers in BOTH HI and FL, instead havinga  single customer in either HI or Fl.

[Relevant Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ksX.png) and [Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoS5V.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to only return those sales people that do not have customers in either HI or FL (or both). If so, you can use `having` to check if a group has any customers in either HI or FL and exclude them if they do:

```
SELECT s.salesperson_id, s.salesperson_lname
FROM salesperson_t AS s 
INNER JOIN customer_t AS c on s.salesperson_id=c.salesperson_id
GROUP BY s.salesperson_id, s.salesperson_lname
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN c.state IN ('HI', 'FL') THEN 1 END) = 0
```